# Elasticsearch - Nested field sorting

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index defined by the following :

```json
    {
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "firstName": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "lastName": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "affiliations": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "organisation": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "team": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "dateBeginning": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    },
                    "dateEnding": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    },
                    "country": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Basically, for each researcher (`researchers` is how I named my index) I want to sort the the affiliations by dateBeginning, in descending order. I've read about inner hits in the EL official doc, and not being exactly sure how it works I've tried this for researcher with `_id : 3` :

```json
    {
    "query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "affiliations",
        "query": {
            "match": { "_id": 3 }
        },
        "inner_hits": {
            "sort" : [
            {
                "affiliations.dateBeginning" : {
                    "order" : "desc",
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "affiliations",
                        "filter": {
                            "term": { "_id": 3 }
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
            ]
        } 
      }
      }
    }
```

And it doesn't really work.

Having two affiliation for researchers with `_id  : 3`, with one dateBeginning set on `2015-06-30`, and the other on `2017-06-30`. So I've tried this also :

```json
    {
    "sort" : [
            {
                "affiliations.dateBeginning" : {
                    "order" : "desc",
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "affiliations"
                }   
            }
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "affiliations",
            "query": {
                "match": { "_id": 3 }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

And it doesn't sort the affiliations by dateBeginning.

I've also tried to do it with the SQL API (since I'm more familiar with SQL language), and still, I can't get the data I want.

So I'm quite new to ElasticSearch, I'm using version `7.10`, and I don't know what else to do.

Any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong here ?

**EDIT**

here's an example of a document from that index:

```json
            {
            "took": 1,
            "timed_out": false,
            "_shards": {
                "total": 1,
                "successful": 1,
                "skipped": 0,
                "failed": 0
            },
            "hits": {
                "total": {
                    "value": 1,
                    "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": 1.0,
                "hits": [{
                    "_index": "researchers",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "3",
                    "_score": 1.0,
                    "_source": {
                        "firstName": "Kimmich",
                        "lastName": "Yoshua",
                        "affiliations": [{
                                "organisation": "University of Ottawa",
                                "team": "Neural Network Elite Team",
                                "dateBeginning": "2015-06-30",
                                "datEnding": "2017-01-31",
                                "country": "Canada"
                            },
                            {
                                "organisation": "University of Montréal",
                                "team": "Picture processing team",
                                "dateBeginning": "2017-06-30",
                                "dateEnding": null,
                                "country": "Canada"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just edited the post with a sample index doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you're inside the nested query, the inner hits don't need the extra nested query. Remove it and the sort will work properly:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "affiliations",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "_id": 3
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "sort": [
          {
            "affiliations.dateBeginning": {
              "order": "desc"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this wouldn't sort the top-level hits -- only the inner hits.
But you can sort on the top level by the values of `affiliations.dateBeginning` like so:

```
POST researchers/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "affiliations.dateBeginning": {
        "order": "desc",
        "nested_path": "affiliations"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but note that the syntax is now slightly different: instead of `path` we're saying `nested_path`.

Comment: Working just fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just one thing though : I think the syntax according to the official ES doc is actually `path` and the `nested_path` will be deprecated

Comment: True true. I'm glad they deprecated it in favor of consistency.